# Is there for QT an equivalent to Microsoft Blend or Adobe tools?

Tags: qt, user-interface, adobe, expression-blend

After working extensively with Microsoft development tools, I migrated to ubuntu and QT for research purposes.

QT is a great framework, up to now there's nothing I needed and it's not there.
However the tools-ecosystem around QT is a bit behind microsoft's ecosystem (V.Studio, Expression Suite)

More specifically, QT Creator is quite nice, but the lack of a 'standard' tool like MS-Blend (which I think is a must, complementary to V.Studio) or the various Adobe tools is pretty apparent, in the case of developing fancy interfaces, animations etc. And Animations (e.g. menu's apperaing/disapperaing from the side) are a bit painful to hardcode without a 'graphical'-tool.

Do you have any tool to propose for this reason, that I'm not aware of?

PS - Just to avoid misunderstandings, I know about qml/Qt_Quick/qdesigner/qt_Animation - http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/animation-overview.html. I'm referring to accombining software that make's life easier and reduces time needed for hardcoding stuff

Comment: If you need fancy animations you could use Qt Quick ([documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtquick.html), [Qt Quick demos in YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8G4U7QWRajg)). And by the way, it is Qt, not QT.

Comment: Hi Roku, thanks for your answer. I'm aware of Qt Quick, I wonder if there is a graphical tool with which you can "record" animations with a timeline (in a "WYSIWYG way") and then trigger/pause/stop them in your code, instead of hardcoding timings/coordinates/etc. Something like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kunrQlABHZA 2:30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Direct answer:**

No there is no tool available in Qt arena that matches the capabilities of Microsoft Blend.

[There is this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800219/qt-versus-wpf-net), which discusses a similar situation; a comparison between .NET and Qt in terms of UI designing.